# Transaction log is full for the database "XXX" due to LOG_BACKUP

Tags: mysql

I faced the problem

> "Transaction log is full for the database "XXX" due to LOG_BACKUP"

Due to this problem, insertion/updation/deletion operation is not happening in the database.

My database LDF file is more than 80 GB.

When I'm trying to shrink the transaction log(LDF) of the corresponding database, it won't shrink as I referred the below mentioned links.When I'm trying to increase the INTIAL_SIZE of LDF file, it is not increased.

Please help on the same.

Comment: Are you sure you've tagged this with the right database engine?  I've only seen LDF files with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Formatting text